# Правильный перевод String в int

Tags: java, android

Не получается привести значение string к int. В чем может быть проблема?

Код

```
public void setDelayNote(Context context, String uniqId, String date, String time) {
    ***
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra("id", uniqId);

    int i = Integer.parseInt(uniqId);

    Log.i("AkvaforAdmin", "cod " + i);
    // PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, uniqId, intent, 0);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, (int) System.currentTimeMillis(), intent, 0);
    ***
}
```

На `int i = Integer.parseInt(uniqId)` выдает ошибку

Логи

```
2019-05-11 00:41:54.331 17394-17394/ru.bruimafia.akvaforadmin E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: ru.bruimafia.akvaforadmin, PID: 17394
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:402)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921) 
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1557524514327"
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:611)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:643)
        at ru.bruimafia.akvaforadmin.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.setDelayNote(AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.java:55)
        at ru.bruimafia.akvaforadmin.activities.AddNoteActivity.addNote(AddNoteActivity.java:108)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:397) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6291) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24931) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:101) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7529) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: `1557524514327` не поместится в `int` при всем желании

Comment: @extrn, но тогда почему работает код `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()`?

Comment: Это разные вещи, очевидно. Хотя авторы могли бы сделать, чтобы старшая часть числа обрезалась при парсинге. А еще они могли бы сделать, чтобы корректно парсилась строка "тысяча три" или "несколько", но не стали почему-то. Так что имеем то, что имеем.

Comment: Или `new BigInteger(uniqId)`.

Comment: `(int) System.currentTimeMillis()` - работает, потому что Здесь Вы явно приводите `long` к `int` - то есть делаете это намеренно, понимая что старшие байты будут утеряны (это основы языка - Вы их знать обязаны). Со строкой всё неоднозначно - поэтому реализация не имеет права втихомолку обрезать полученное число и выдать `int`. Из соображений типо-безопасности - это должно быть сделано явным образом. То есть парсим в переменную большего размера и приводим к желаемому типу, теряя при этом "лишнее".

Answer (score 1):

int - 32-битное число, оно принимает значение от минус до плюс 2 млрд. Используйте long

Comment: ни в коем случае. double имеет неполное покрытие целых. Целые пачки достаточно крупных целых чисел при парсинге в double дадут одинаковый результат. И какой смысл парсить однозначно целое в число с плавающей точкой?

Comment: в double у вас 1 бит знак числа, 52 бита мантиса, и 1 бит знак порядка 10 бит порядок. Самое большое значение мантиссы - 52 символа, порядка - 1024. То есть в double мы можем хранить число  с количеством знаков 1024-52, что явно больше, чем 52 знака. Все оставшиеся знаки считаются заполненными нулями. Очевидно, что прибавка к подобному числа единицы, или даже миллиарда, никак его не изменит, т.к. точность значительно меньше. в случае с long'ом число, содержащее 53 единицы подряд, не уместится а мантиссу, а значит не может быть отображено в double точно, оно будет округлено

Comment: Вспомнил что к мантисе надо прибавлять единицу, это портит мой пример, но не суть. Из-за мантисы в 52 бита есть 64битные целые числа, которые при переводе в double дадут одно тоже

Comment: Как-то слишком сбивчево выходит... Переведите в Double числа от Long.MaxValue-511 до Long.MaxValue, все они дадут побитно совпадающие Double

Comment: Тогда вопрос что вы хотите делать с этим числом. Если оно будет подвержено каким-то операция - используем BigInt. Но большинство программистов с такой длинной арифметикой никогда не сталкивалась и не столкнется, и если это статичное значение - храним его байт-массивом/строкой. В любом случае переводить такие большие числа из целого в число с плавающей точкой просто так - неблагодарное дело. Проблемы быть могут, а польза - весьма сомнительна